# How to execute gitlab-ci jobs on specific events

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm learning gitlab-ci and I'm having a difficult time setting up the .yml file to run a specific job only when a certain trigger token is used or when a branch is merged into master.

I've read through gitlab-ci docs and reviewed several examples. Still, I'm not seeing what I'm looking for.

*Edit: Answering part of my own question, using `only: - master` should only run the job for merges and pushes to master branch.

```
.build_template: &base_defs
  stage: build_base
  <<: *tags_defs
  variables:
    FILE_VER: "3.4"
  script:
    - docker build -t "${DEV_BASE}:latest" "${VERSION}/devel/base"
      --build-arg FILE_VERSION=${FILE_VER}
  only:
    - master
    - ~ WHEN TRIGGER TOKEN MATCHES = K3K3K3K3 ~
```

Comment: What are you inserting with `<<: *tags_defs`? Please explain your "trigger token".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
only:
  variables:
    - token == "..."
```

and make it work with one of the predefined [gitlab variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)?
Reference: [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables)

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. I would have thought there is a predefined gitlab variable for something like $TRIGGER_TOKEN. This would allow only/except to be used not only on triggers but specific trigger tokens.